# glsl - Can I pass a constant to a function without the coping the constant into the parameter?

Tags: glsl, vulkan

I have a glsl function witch can accept one of several const arrays and does some operation using information from that array. For example:

```
const uint A[] = { /* 10 values here */ };
const uint B[] = { /* 10 different values here */ };
const uint C[] = { /* 10 different values here */ };

float doSomethingWithArray(const uint arr[10], float x){
  // do some operations which use the constant array and a non-constant value. Eg:
  uint a = arr[floor(x)];
  uint b = arr[a] * 2 + 3;
  float c = (b + a) * x;
  return c;
}
```

If I were to call this function, passing one of the constant arrays as a parameter `doSomethingWithArray(A, 5.0)`, I am worried the arrays will be copied into the parameter, slowing down the program.

> https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#Parameters
>
> values passed to functions are copied into parameters when the function is called

This makes me think it would be faster to have 3 separate functions each of which use a different constant array. This way, the arrays would not have to be copied. For example:

```
float doSomethingWithA(float x){
  uint a = A[floor(x)];
  uint b = A[a] * 2 + 3;
  float c = (b + a) * x;
  return c;
}
float doSomethingWithB(float x){
  uint a = B[floor(x)];
  uint b = B[a] * 2 + 3;
  float c = (b + a) * x;
  return c;
}
float doSomethingWithC(float x){
  uint a = C[floor(x)];
  uint b = C[a] * 2 + 3;
  float c = (b + a) * x;
  return c;
}
```

However, this results in a huge amount of repeated code especially if there are more constant arrays. Is there a way to do this operation without the arrays being copied and without having code repeated?

I am using glslc to compile to a .spv.

Comment: "*I am using glslc to compile to a .spv.*" Have you considered looking at the generated SPIR-V?

Comment: From what i have seen, functions are usually inlined automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not using Vulcan as my gfx card do not support it but in GLSL I have at my disposal I can use macro for the function instead something like this:

```
#define doSomethingWithArray(arr,x) ((arr[arr[floor(x)]] * 2 + 3 + arr[floor(x)]) * x)
```

Macros will hard code the 3 instances for you ... Here an example (fragment shader):

```
#version 420 core
out layout(location=0) vec4 col;
#define test(arr,x) ((arr[arr[int(floor(x))]] * 2 + 3 + arr[int(floor(x))]) * x)
const uint A[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
const uint B[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
const uint C[]={2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1};
void main()
    {
    float x=3.75;
    col=vec4(test(A,x),test(B,x),test(C,x),1.0);
    }
```

The  `#version 420 core` is the first version that does not throw bunch of warnings and errors on stuff you use (like const arrays etc ..) on my nVidia